# How to Connect 2 Cockroachdb Cluster in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, migration, cockroachdb

I have the following problem. In Kubernetes I have 2 clusters that I want to connect via Join. The clusters are running. The connection must be secure. I have created the CA of the old cluster. However where they might need to pass to the new one I haven't found. There is not much about it on the cockroach pages.

On both I have
tls:
enabled: true
certs:
provided: true